# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () when using firebase cloud functions to access cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know that there are similar posts about this, but I tried all of them and non worked.
I wrote this function for getting the user's name from the UID. I have a collection called users, with each user's uid as the name of the document, and a value called `displayName` in it.

```
exports.getDisplayName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(context.auth){
        const uid = data.uid
        return admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}`).get().then(doc=>{return{name: doc.data().displayName}})
    }else{
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }
})
```

When it deploy it everything works fine but when I call it I get these 2 errors and I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: INTERNAL
```

I have another function that works fine:

```
exports.getUidFromEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(context.auth){
        const email = data.email
        return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email).then((userRecord)=>{ return {user: userRecord.uid}})
    }else{
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }
})
```

edit: the error it says is this:

```
Unhandled error FirebaseError: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.
at FirebaseDatabaseError.FirebaseError [as constructor]   (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
at new FirebaseDatabaseError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:205:23)
at DatabaseService.ensureUrl (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database-internal.js:97:15)
at DatabaseService.getDatabase (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database-internal.js:65:26)
at FirebaseApp.database (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:228:24)
at FirebaseNamespace.fn (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:191:45)
at /workspace/index.js:17:22
at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
    errorInfo: {
        code: 'database/invalid-argument',
        message: "Can't determine Firebase Database URL."
    }
}
```

Comment: The uid is usually part of the CONTEXT - I'm GUESSING (because you don't show it) your "works fine" is called with a payload of an object that has an email field.  Your FIRST function also tries to get the uid from the payload - but I'm betting you meant to get it from the context.auth...

Comment: @LeadDreamer so I'm not trying to get the displayName of the user that called the function, but ANY user's name, and you can pass in the uid of the that user. (The reason for this function is that there are places where the user is just stored by the uid, so I need to get their name so people can actually know who that person is)

Comment: Hi, maybe you can [check the logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#viewing_logs) for your Firebase Function. In there you could view the full traceback and maybe this is helpful to debug your code.

Comment: @llompalles ok I checked the logs and made an edit to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue. It was because I was using Cloud Firestore instead of Realtime database, because a lot of the examples and docs are using it, I thought it just had a different syntax 
here's the fixed code:

```
exports.getDisplayName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(context.auth){
        const uid = data.uid

        return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).get().then(doc=>{
            console.log(doc)
            return{name: doc.data().displayName}
        })

    }else{
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }
})
```

it's `admin.firestore()` not `admin.database()`

Comment: Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!